# Shadow Hunters: Holy Robe versus black card weapon

Tags: shadow-hunters

The text of a black card weapon is like that:

> If your attack is successful, you give 1 extra point of damage.

And the Holy Robe is:

> Your attacks do 1 less damage and the amount of damage you receive from attacks is reduced by 1 point.

So if someone attacks with a black card weapon a played protected by the Holy Robe and rolls a 1, what happens?
Does the player take 1 or 0 damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way of considering this is to imagine that Holy Robe reads "the amount of damage to receive from successful attacks is reduced by 1 point".  If so, it's clear that an attack with a black card weapon would deal 1 + 1 - 1 = 1 point of damage.

Otherwise you have to ponder the question of whether a Holy Robe could make an attack "unsuccessful" *after* damage is dealt.  I think it's easier just to go with the implication of the rulebook, which states in the Attack section "If both dice rolled have the same number, your attack fails and no damage is inflicted"; I take this to mean that an attack *fails* if it would do less than 1 damage based solely on the die roll, and *succeeds* otherwise.

Once we have determined that the attack is successful and would all else being equal deal damage, we apply all modifiers, which in the case of your question above cancel each other out.